# finding element in a fieldset on a web form

Tags: c#, selenium

New to selenium with c#, am trying to locate radio button on a fieldset form:

```
        driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).Click();
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(".//*[@id='fieldset'");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Complaints and suggestions')])[2]")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".wpcf7-list-item.first>label>input")).Click();

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='CatalystResident' value='Yes']")).Click();
        var location = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required"));
        SelectElement catalystLocation = new SelectElement(location);
        catalystLocation.SelectByText("London-Brent");
```

Getting error message element can not be located. Thanks

Relevant html code

```
<div class="anti-social-form">
```

Comment: are you sure it's on the page? have you tried using wait() for a determined amount of time to see if it appears?

Comment: Could you share the relevant html?

Comment: Relevant html code                                                                             <div class="anti-social-form">                                                                         
<fieldset id="fieldset" class="firstset">
<fieldset id="fieldset_3" class="secondset" style="display: none;">
<fieldset id="fieldset_resident_details" class="fifthset" style="display: block;">
<fieldset id="fieldset_contant_method" class="sixthset">
<fieldset id="fieldset_perpetrator_details" class="fifthset" style="display: none;">
<fieldset>
<p>
<a>
</div>